# Using include in class properly

Tags: php, oop

I have a main class in `index.php`:

```
class myClass {

    public function lorem() {
        include_once 'extendClass.php';
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->lorem();
    }

}

// run class
new extendClass();
```

I need to `include_once 'extendClass.php'` within the `lorem()` function.

In my `extendClass.php` file, I extend the class function with:

```
class extendClass extends myClass {

    public function lorem(){
        echo "foo bar";
        parent::lorem();

    }

}
```

When I use `new extendClass()` in `index.php`, I get an error because the `include_once()` is not triggered. What's the solution to this puzzle?

Note: `include_once()` must be within `myClass`.

Comment: You can't nest class declarations.

Comment: @Rizier123 Is my only option to make two completely separate classes in this case? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes. Also how should that nested class even be able to extend from a class which isn't even defined yet? So you probably want to define it under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two problems here

1. You're creating a child class that's overwriting the `lorem()` function. You would have to explicitly call `parent::lorem()` to get to it
2. Even if you call it, that parent function doing the `include` means that anything defined in that function is **locally scoped to that function**. So that means your child function can't inherit it (at least not without some sort of `return` declaration)

You need to move the include outside your class declaration

```
include_once 'extendClass.php';
class myClass {

    public function lorem() {
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->lorem();
    }

}

// run class
new extendClass();
```